# Mongodb join table with javascript

Tags: mongodb, join

I'm trying to display each Client with their address. In SQL I'll do a simple query for do it, but with mongodb join doesn't exist and I don't know how to do it.

```
db.Adresse.insert(
    [{
        Numero: 13,             // id: 561389265589912403e9e58d
        Rue: "Street",
        CP: 1234,
        Ville: "Springfield"    
    },
    {
        Numero: 154,            // id: 561389265589912403e9e58e
        Rue: "De La Gare",
        CP: 4567,
        Ville: "Nirvana"
    },
    {
        Numero: 1,              // id: 561389265589912403e9e58f
        Rue: "Lucas",
        CP: 1000,
        Ville: "Tatooine"
    },
    {
        Numero: 67,             // id: 561389265589912403e9e590
        Rue: "De La Loi",
        CP: 15009,
        Ville: "Arkham"
    }]
);

db.Client.insert(
    [{
        Nom: "Cobain",
        Prenom: "Kurt",
        Adresses:["561389265589912403e9e58e"] 
    },
    {
        Nom: "Reznor",
        Prenom: "Trent",
        Adresses:["561389265589912403e9e58d","561389265589912403e9e590"]
    },
    {
        Nom: "Cavalera",
        Prenom: "Max",
        Adresses:["561389265589912403e9e58f"]
    },
    {
        Nom: "Love",
        Prenom: "Courtney",
        Adresses:["561389265589912403e9e58e"]
    }]
);
```

I want display like this:

```
Cobain Kurt 15 De La Gare 4567 Nirvana 
...
```

I have tried with cursor but I don't have result.

I ve try this but itsn't work

```
db.Client.find().forEach(
    function(dataClient){
        dataClient.Client = db.Client.findOne({"_id": dataClient.Client});
        dataClient.Adresse = db.Client.find({"_id": dataClient.Adresses}).toArray();
        db.dataClients.insert(dataClient);

    }
);
db.dataClients.find().pretty()
```

;